# Is there a JQuery plugin for the Kens Burns effect?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, image, templates

I just want a very simple plugin...**not a slideshow** plugin
I just have 1 div, and 1 image.

I want the image to move within that div (left/right, top/down), but do not have white space showing. Naturally, the image is bigger than the div, allowing this effect to happen.

Comment: @times , you can  implement with jquery' animate right...it should be easy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes there is! : http://tobia.github.com/CrossSlide/[1](http://tobia.github.com/CrossSlide/)

Comment: What would it fade into, or how would the end of the transition look, an empty div?

Comment: I want it to just....stop, or go back and forth slowly

Comment: Then you should be able to add a single image and call the crossSlideFreeze() method. Or add two of the same image and rotate them in and out. It's definitely doable w/ that plugin.

Comment: @TIMEX: Just give it the same image twice and you should get what you want.

Comment: @jyoseph thanks for this link....i also need something like this

Comment: @everyone , is there anyway we can add some questions as favorites or so...

Answer (score 0):

1 Preset backgroundPosition 
2 Preset the Background-image of your target div to your image.
3.To Pan: Play with the coords of backgroundPosition: '1px 240px', opacity for readability
4.Use a long timeout and or ease for animates.
5.however as far as i know zooming is not viable this way.

It looks like background-size: 50% 50% or -moz-background-size: 100% 100% dont work.

```
$('div').animate({
    backgroundPosition: "10px 100px"
  }, 5000).animate({
    backgroundPosition: "10px 10px"
  }, 5000);
```